# New to the C language; strcat is having unexpected results

Tags: c

I am converting a script from Bash to C for work.  I am new to C.  Lots for me to learn.  I have code I have debugging.  The printf of a variable with contents built from substr is outputting unexpected results.

As a learning concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char one[5] = "abcde";
    char two[3] = "fgh";
    char three[8] = "ijklmnop";

    int size = strlen( one ) + strlen( two ) + strlen( three );
    char str[ size ];

    strcpy( str, one );
    strcat( str, "_" );
    strcat( str, two );
    strcat( str, "_" );
    strcat( str, three);

    printf( "string is: %s\n", str );
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting results like:

```
string is: nop abcdefghijklmnopabd
```

Clearly memory isn't being properly managed or something to that degree.  I am confused because the above seems like a pretty textbook use case of the functions.

I have tried a number of debugging technics; however, this is the lowest stack language I have ever used.

Comment: None of the array sizes allow for the terminating 0. `str` also doesn't allow for the underscores. https://godbolt.org/z/b1EK7svrc

Comment: I assume you're using C for efficiency.   However, you're defeating the purpose here because every call to `strcat` or `strlen` has to iterate through the string from the beginning in order to find its length.  Also your string size calculations will be hard to maintain.  If you can put an upper bound like 4096 on the size of the result string, then just do:  `char buffer[4096]; sprintf(buffer, "%s-%s-%s", one, two, three);`.  You can even use the return value if you need to know how long the resulting string is.  And you could use `snprintf` for extra safety.

Comment: "_New to C_" Then you should learn the importance of **learning** before **doing**! Chapter 1.9 of the K&R Bible clearly shows the difference between an array of characters and a C string (that is defined with a terminating `'\0'`.) Basics...

Comment: I have implemented all the changes.  I am no longer experiencing the issue.  I have a new issue.

Answer (score 7):

You have undefined behaviour because your arrays do not leave room for the null terminator.

```
char one[5] = "abcde";
```

This is not a valid C string. The following is:

```
char one[6] = "abcde";
```

Or just let the compiler figure out how big the array needs to be:

```
char one[] = "abcde";
```

Having done that you need to make `str` big enough to hold the null terminator and the two `'_'` characters. While unlikely to have any practical impact in this case, it would be more correct to type `size` as `size_t` than `int`.

```
size_t size = strlen( one ) + strlen( two ) + strlen( three );
char str[ size + 3 ];
```

As you do not modify `one`, `two`, or `three` you might simply have declared them as pointers to string literals.

```
const char *one = "abcde";
const char *two = "fgh";
const char *three = "ijklmnop";
```

Comment: `size + sizeof("__")` — which is the same as `3`, but explains better where the value comes from.  `sizeof()` includes the null byte, unlike `strlen()`.

Answer (score 3):

Let the compiler count for you:

`char one[5] = "abcde";` -> `char one[] = "abcde";`

or better yet: `const char *one = "abcde";` if you don't need to modify those strings.

`strcpy` and `strcat` are prone to buffer overflows, consider using `snprintf`, an advantage of `snprintf` is that (with a little help from `malloc`) you don't need to hardcode the final size (`size + 3` in your case)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *one = "abcde";
    const char *two = "fgh";
    const char *three = "ijklmnop";
    const char *fmt = "%s_%s_%s";
    size_t size = 1 + (size_t)snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, one, two, three);
    char *str = malloc(size);

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(str, size, fmt, one, two, three);
        printf("string is: %s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can use `char str[size];` as in your snippet, but personally I prefer to avoid VLA's.

Comment: And if `str` is only ever printed, then save yourself the trouble and just `printf("%s-%s-%s", one, two, three);`

Comment: And for consistency with the question, replace dashes with underscores.